# Proving $3^{100} > 5\cdot10^{47}$ with integral representation

Tags: integration, inequality, number-comparison

I want to prove that $3^{100} > 5\cdot10^{47}$ without using calculator or any approximation of the logarithm.
I tought about finding an integral representation of $(3^{100} - 5\cdot10^{47})$ with the integrand non negative in the chosen integration interval (something like [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425468/integral-representation-of-frac355113-pi)), but I don't know how to chose the integrand. Do you have any ideas?
Or even any elegant way to prove the inequality?

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2276227/25554

Comment: “Without any approximation of the logarithm” is pretty broad.  For example,  is it really forbidden to argue that $3^5< 2^8 < 3^6$ therefore $\frac58<\log_3{2} < \frac 68$?

Comment: @MJD no it's not forbidden! I just wanted to know if there is an alternative way, and maybe use that in other kind of problems like that. If you have a solution, please feel free to post, thank you!

Comment: If logarithms base $~10~$ are allowed, then the problem becomes trivial because $~\log_{10}(3) \approx 0.477,~$ while $~\log_{10}(5) \approx 0.699.$

Comment: @user2661923 But then the question is where you can obtain such good approximations of $\log_{10} 3$ and $\log_{10} 5$ without extensive floating-point calculations. The two sides are quite close ($47.71 > 47.70$) so tricks like the one I suggested, based on small integers and inaccurate estimates, will not suffice.

Comment: @MJD No calculator needed.  See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4148787/comparing-e4-2-and-50-without-calculator/4148955?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C20.6129#4148955).

Answer (score 7):

We have by hand calculation

- $3^{10} =59049>59\cdot 10^3$
- $59^2=3481>348\cdot10$
- $348^2=121104>12\cdot 10^4$

then

$$3^{100}>348\cdot 12^2\cdot 10^{43}>5.01\cdot 10^{47}$$

Comment: I'd say given that the bound is tight, this has to be the most efficient way to solve by approximation(+1)

Comment: @DS Yes I think it is a reasonable way using only hand calculation.

Comment: @DS We can improve a little bit using $348^2>12\cdot 10^4$.

Comment: @user very smart and simple! I know that the integral method would be much more complex, but do you think that it's possible to find a suitable integrand function?

Comment: @user967210 I'm not sure how can find such kind of solution, maybe someone else is working on that. Glad you appreciate also this alternative way. Bye

Comment: Unclear if the logarithm approach in an answer that I linked to, in a comment following the original question, is good enough to confidently solve the problem.  The approach definitely gives 3 decimal places for $~\log_{10} (2)~$ and $~\log_{10} (3).~$  This becomes borderline sufficient.  Going for the 4th decimal place depends on getting the 4th decimal place for $~\log_{e}(10).~$ Unclear if that kind of accuracy can be confidently attained, using my approach.